# Syntax highlighting with QSyntaxHighlighter in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have been trying to use the `QSyntaxHighlighter` module for highlighting syntax with `QTextEdit()`. I have looked [here](https://carsonfarmer.com/2009/07/syntax-highlighting-with-pyqt/) and [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Python%20syntax%20highlighting). Unfortunately, both are pyqt4. For example, pyqt5 doesn't use `QString()` or `QStringList()` anymore and suggests using `str()` and `list()` respectively. Even if I make the above changes I am unable to make the appropriate changes to the following code:

```
def highlightBlock( self, text ):
  for rule in self.highlightingRules:
    expression = QRegExp( rule.pattern )
    index = expression.indexIn( text )
    while index >= 0:
      length = expression.matchedLength()
      self.setFormat( index, length, rule.format )
      index = text.indexOf( expression, index + length )
  self.setCurrentBlockState( 0 )
```

The error that I get is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'indexOf'`. So what should be the appropriate changes in this case for pyqt5? I am not looking forward to use `QScintilla`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace

```py
index = text.indexOf(expression, index + length)
```

with

```py
index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)
```

which should do the trick ;)